# Generic error occurred in GDI+

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+

I am getting the error "Generic error occurred in GDI+" in my sample code below. What I do is that I make a request to get response for many jpeg files available at live site.
When I get response, I save the file to my application's local folder 
and converting these images to binary (bytes of array) so that I can save it into database.

```
private byte[] GetBinaryImageData(string imgURL)
{
    HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(imgURL);
    WebResponse response = Request.GetResponse();
    Stream str = response.GetResponseStream();
    System.Drawing.Image objTempImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(str);
    objTempImg.Save(FileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];
    fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
    fileStream.Close();
    return buffer;
}
```

i don't get this error for all images, but it occurs for some of images. Anybody know the solution? I have already spent 2 days to oversome this

Comment: Do the same images throw the error each time? Which line is throwing the error? Is there a pattern that the error-causing images follow?

Comment: I recently found out that a "Generic error occurred in GDI+" error can occur if the destination directory does not exist.

Comment: yes and also if u are trying to save a file wiht illegal characters in the name e.g. swivel/action.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to guess; it is having problems with handles occasionally, for the reason that **you aren't disposing things correctly**. This is *especially* important for things like GDI+. Introduce a few `using` statements to your code, since pretty much **all** of those objects are `IDisposable`:

```
HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(imgURL);
using(WebResponse response = Request.GetResponse())
using(Stream str = response.GetResponseStream())
using(System.Drawing.Image objTempImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(str))
{
    objTempImg.Save(FileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
return File.ReadAllBytes(FileName);
```

(note I changed your file-reading code too, since it was hugely unreliable; it is **incorrect** to assume that `Stream.Read` actually reads all the data; you are supposed to check the return value and loop; but since you want it all, `File.ReadAllBytes` is easier).

Comment: still m getting same error for same images.i used your above whole code of reading image file bytes.

Comment: @ravidev did you try, as per Andrew's answer, copying the data to a `MemoryStream`? i.e. `using(var ms = new MemoryStream()) { str.CopyTo(ms); ms.Position = 0; using(var objTempImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)) { objTempImg.Save(...); } }` - i.e. combining both sets of answers?

Comment: using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
    byte[] temp = new byte[ImgSize];
    int read = 0;
    while ((read = str.Read(temp, 0, temp.Length)) > 0)
    {
    ms.Write(temp, 0, read);
    }
    return ms.ToArray();
    }

Comment: If i use MemoryStream, will this affect my CPU or performance of my application??

Comment: @ravidev it won't impact CPU; if the image is huge it might need a bit more memory, but ... you're **already** then loading a huge image, so that is a false concern.

Comment: @MarcGravell, thanks for help. For me, this trick reduced number of errors but some files still cannot be processed. If you have time, take a look on my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957708/jpeg-library-to-read-all-images-in-dotnetx`

Answer (score 2):

Judging by [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/Default.aspx?id=814675) it appears the stream the image is loaded from must exist for the lifetime of the image or bad things can happen.

I've run into this from time to time and found it easiest to copy the image data to a memory stream or a file my process controls and construct the image from that.

From the linked article:

> GDI+, and therefore the System.Drawing namespace, may defer the
>   decoding of raw image bits until the bits are required by the image.
>   Additionally, even after the image has been decoded, GDI+ may
>   determine that it is more efficient to discard the memory for a large
>   Bitmap and to re-decode later. Therefore, GDI+ must have access to the
>   source bits for the image for the life of the Bitmap or the Image
>   object.
>
> To retain access to the source bits, GDI+ locks any source file, and
>   forces the application to maintain the life of any source stream, for
>   the life of the Bitmap or the Image object.

Comment: Good catch; indeed, GDI does tend to want to seek (which is **not** a reliable operation, especially on a `NetworkStream`)

Comment: It's one of those leaky abstractions where a useful error message could save a lot of people a lot of pain :]

Comment: yeah; it should really check whether the stream is seekable... not sure if that is available on the *unmanaged* stream, though