# JPEG manipulations and dotnet - GDI+ exception

Tags: .net, image, jpeg

For instance, here is sample JPEG which I cannot SAVE (!) but can read (e.g. find out width and height) using standard dotnet classes. Original file:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5079317/184809_1_original.jpg

After saving same image in windows image editor, all works great:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5079317/184809_1_resaved.jpg

I noticed this bug long time ago but it wasn't major problem. But in current project I have thousands of such images and i really need some kind of solution.

Which 3rd party libraries could be used?

Here is how I am reading:

```
public ImageFile SaveImage(HttpPostedFileBase file, string fileNameWithPath, bool splitImage, out string errorMessage)
{
  try
  {
    using (var stream = file.InputStream)
    {
      using (Image source = Image.FromStream(stream))
      {
        return SaveImage(source, fileNameWithPath, splitImage, out errorMessage);
        // which actually do source.Save(fileNameWithPath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        // Exception: A generic error occurred in GDI+.
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resizing of original image to same size solves problem:

```
Image img2 = FixedSize(source, source.Width, source.Height, true);
img2.Save(path, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what library you're using for SaveImage, but if you're just using .NET, invoke the following Save method (with void return type) on the Image object, and return whatever object you need based on the System.Drawing.Image object from your new file.

```
source.Save(@"C:\{path}\184809_1_resaved.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Without having more details, this is the best I can offer, since I don't know what the implementation of an ImageFile class looks like.  ImageFile is your current return type, but I just changed the type to make it work.

```
public System.IO.Stream SaveImage(HttpPostedFileBase file, string fileNameWithPath, bool splitImage, out string errorMessage)
{
    try
    {
        using (var stream = file.InputStream)
        {
            using (System.Drawing.Image source = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream))
            {
                source.Save(@"C:\resaved.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                source.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                stream.Position = 0;
                errorMessage = string.Empty;
                return stream;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        errorMessage = e.Message.ToString();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iirc some formats need to seek, which isn't supported on all streams. You might try buffering in a memory-stream:

```
using (var input = file.InputStream)
using (var buffer = new MemoryStream())
{
    input.CopyTo(buffer);
    buffer.Position = 0; // rewind
    using (Image source = Image.FromStream(buffer))
    { ... Etc  as before ... }
}
```